# VS 2013 Custom assemblies load Rdlc report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, rdlc

My external assemblies are not loading while i run report...

it does compile with no error but report could not run the error shows :

```html
Error while loading code module: ‘ResultAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null’. Details: Could not load file or assembly 'ResultAssembly, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
In VS 2013
```

I have added my assembly in C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\12.0\Bin.... it works fine when i compile my solution

But report not running :(